# Where are NDEBUG and _DEBUG Defined in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2015, assert

I can go to the settings of a default Visual Studio 2010 project and see `NDEBUG` or `_DEBUG` defined in "Configuration Properties">>"C/C++">>"Preprocessor"'s "Preprocessor Definitions":
[image: Visual Studio 2010 Project Settings]

If I go to the settings of a default Visual Studio 2015 project "Preprocessor Definitions" is empty!
[image: Visual Studio 2015 Project Settings]

I don't even see `NDEBUG` or `_DEBUG` mentioned at all in the Visual Studio 2015 .vcxproj. I know that it is correctly defined though because `assert(false)` only fires in the Debug configuration. Where has Microsoft tucked these definitions away in Visual Studio 2015? Is it possible for me to modify them, or has that been taken from me?

**EDIT:**
[Niall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33154591/2642059) is correct. What I didn't understand was that the `assert` happened differently if triggered in Release configuration. This program doesn't pop up an `assert` dialog, but it doesn't execute the `system("pause")` either:

```
void main() {
    assert(false);
    system("pause");
}
```

Instead when I run it in Release configuration from Visual Studio I see the console window pop up and immediately close, so I *assumed* the `assert` didn't fire cause I didn't see an `assert` dialog. *However* if I run the compiled Release executable from the terminal it immediately ends, *but* it outputs:

> Assertion failed: false, file temp.cpp, line 9

So the assertion *is* firing in Release configuration, it just doesn't pop up an `assert` dialog. This means that `NDEBUG` is in fact *not* being defined.

Comment: those are still there. Did  you start with an empty project? Sometimes when you start with an empty project some things are not automatically generated.

Comment: @engf-010 The second picture is taken from an empty console project. You can clearly see that those are *not* still there. However the empty console project does fire on `assert(false)` in Debug configuration but does not fire in Release configuration. So clearly whatever needed to get generated got generated, it's just no longer accessible.

Comment: I believe you. All I can say that my standard console project show them at the usual place for all platforms and configurations.

Comment: "Empty console project" does not mean anything.  It is either an empty project or a console project.  The settings come from the project template, pick Win32 > Win32 Console Application to get started and fall in the pit of success.  The project is ultimately generated by Javascript, the script code is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\VCWizards\AppWiz\Generic\Application\scripts\1033\default.js

Comment: @HansPassant What I meant by empty console project was creating a new console project and in the "Application Settings" dialog checking "Empty Project" Incidentally When I create a new Console Project by this method it does include the `NDEBUG` and `_DEBUG` definitions.

Comment: @engf-010 So I lie, I created an "Empty Project" not a "Console Project" an "Empty Project" is what doesn't have `NDEBUG` or `_DEBUG` defined. However, if I create an "Empty Project" now I get "Preprocessor Definitons" of: "_MBCS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)" So perhaps something has changed since my original creation, however `NDEBUG` and `_DEBUG` are still not showing up and are still defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally these are defined as part of the additional pre processor defines/options and ultimately land up on the command line with a `/D` option switch.

Depending on the project configuration they could be inherited from a parent properties file so may not be immediately visible in the project.

The runtime switches `/MD`, `/MT` and the debug versions `/MDd` and `/MTd` define these as well; in particlar the `_DEBUG`. [The MSDN documentation (here)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kzt1wy3.aspx) for these provides more detail.

From experience, in the case of `NDEBUG`, it may be better to test `#ifndef _DEBUG`. I generally find that more consistent.

Comment: That's what I was thinking too, however they are not on the command line:  /GS /analyze- /W1 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /O2 /Fd"Release\vc140.pdb" /Zc:inline /fp:precise /errorReport:prompt /WX- /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oy- /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\temp.pch"

Comment: IIRC, the runtime switches may also add these in, but I can't remember offhand all the details. I've updated the answer as well.

Comment: Those runtime switches do define the debug symbol as well.

Comment: It looks like the "/**d" options do in fact define `_DEBUG` I need to look further on the `NDEBUG` definition.

Comment: When I switch my Release "Runtime Library" to "/MDd" `NDEBUG` is definitely not defined cause I get an assert. However when left as "/MD" this program immediately exits; it doesn't assert, but it doesn't wait for a keypress at `system("pause")`: `#include <cassert> void main(){assert(false);system("pause");}` Something fishy is going on here. But +1 for putting me on what looks like the right track.

Comment: From experience, in the case of NDEBUG, if may be better to test `#ifndef _DEBUG`. I generally find that more consistent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92426/discussion-between-jonathan-mee-and-niall).

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify why this answer is the correct one.

Comment: "Generally these are defined as part of the additional pre processor defines". If "these" includes `NDEBUG` (and why shouldn't it, otherwise it would simply be `_DEBUG`), I think this answer is simply incorrect.